# Convert enum type back to enum

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, typescript-types

I am using a library which has an enum like the following

```js
enum TestEnum {
  FIRST = 0,
  SECOND = 100,
  THIRD = 200,
  FOURTH = 300,
}
```

It's not exported, but used in another class type like the following

```js
declare class TestClass {
  testEnumProp: TestEnum | string | null;
}
```

Now I need that enum for my own code, but I can't directly use it since it's not directly exported. So I tried something like the following to extract the type

```js
type TestEnumType = Exclude<NonNullable<TestClass['testEnumProp']>,string>
```

Which worked in the following case

```js
const val:TestEnumType = TestEnum.FIRST;
```

But since I do not have access to `TestEnum` directly, I can't use `TestEnum.FIRST` and have to use my extracted type

```js
const val2:TestEnumType = TestEnumType.FIRST;
```

But it doesn't work since `TestEnumType` is a type, but not the enum itself. This is the error I receive on my IDE.

```bash
'TestEnumType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
```

Any idea if I can somehow use `TestEnumType.FIRST` using some TS magic?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @vera. I had this issue before with enums, but recently it came up due to the discussion here - https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/issues/1402

Comment: Which class in the library has this?